# Configuring pop-up in ArcGIS Online web map of spatial intersection of located address and feature?

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a simple web-map with a polygon layer that contains 5 features.  I would like to configure the web-map so that when the user geocodes an address that the the  information of the of the polygon feature appears in the pop-up of the located address.

Is there a way to accomplish this in ArcGIS Online?  If not, what is a viable and simple solution that requires little to no JavaScript modification?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this within the ArcGIS Online map viewer. You would have to create a custom web app to support this case.